# How to start/stop sinatra app in cucumber hook

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cucumber

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I've figured out how to solve my problem:

in the before hook I fork the current process to start my sinatra web app:

```
Before do
  if $pid.nil?
    $pid = fork do
      App.run!
    end
  end
end
```

Notice I have to have the forked PID attributed to a global variable so it doesnt get flushed after each scenario in cucumber. Besides that, I make sure to start my sintra app once in the entire cucumber execution.

Then at the end of my cucumber execution, I kill the child process and wait for it to be cleared prior to terminating the cucumber session:

```
at_exit do
  unless $pid.nil?
    Process.kill "TERM", $pid
    Process.wait $pid
  end
end
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am looking to stub a web app which contain content that will then be used by my application to fetch that content from that stub and do its trick...

What I am looking to achieve is start Sinatra app within cucumber hook... then stop it at end of execution... is that possible?

Below is where I've got so far...

```
#myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :server, 'webrick'

  get '/' do
    'Hello!!!'
  end
end
```

Then in hook:

```
Before do
  App.run!
end
```

The first issue there is that the sinatra app won't run in the background... after solving that problem then I would need to understand if it's easy enough to stop the sinatra session as well...